# warning:Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php

I have a very basic code.That involves sessions and array.

```
$abc=array();
$abc['name']=$db_name; //When i echo this one.It does echo the name i.e. 'Tilak'
$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']=true;
$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name']=$abc['name'];
echo $_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name'];
```

Now when i try to run the code.It shows me a warning stating *cannot use a scalar value as an array* as well as the echo part in the above code  doesn't show anything.

**Question :**

1)Why am i seeing this error and what is the way to resolve this?

2)How to echo the above session.

**Note :**

1)*$db_name* is the name of the username that i get from the database.It works fine and  i get the correct value in *$db_name*.

**Update:**

*Same thing happens even if i do this :*

```
 $_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']=true;
 $_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name']=$db_name;
 echo $_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are defining `$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']=true;`. `true` is a scalar value. Then `$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name']=$db_name;` where you are treating `$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']` as an `array`.

You can simply do `$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name']=$db_name;` and `echo` it.

No need for setting it to `true`. This would work -

```
$abc=array();
$abc['name']=$db_name; //When i echo this one.It does echo the name i.e. 'Tilak'
$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name']=$abc['name'];
echo $_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name'];
```

**Update**

No need to define a blank `array`. When you are setting `$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['name'] = $db_name;`, `$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']` is already defined as an `array`.

```
$_SESSION['userpasswordmatch']['check']= true; // use this for that check
```

Comment: then how do i make an array of session?

Comment: i need that true part as well

Comment: Can you tell me why you need that `true` part?

Comment: i make that part false somewhere which let me pop up my message and this name gives me a drop down menu with the logged user name.

Comment: Then you have to use another index.

Comment: yes this thing does work on online editors but when i run a php file through browser i do get the warning